# How can I assert a response consisting of an array of values to a user defined variable

Tags: xpath, jmeter

I have a Soap request which response returns a set of values under the same tag 
let's say

```
<PricelistDetails>

                        <ServicePricelistDetailInfo>
                           <cost>20</cost>
                        </ServicePricelistDetailInfo>

                       <ServicePricelistDetailInfo>
                           <cost>25</cost>
                        </ServicePricelistDetailInfo>

                        <ServicePricelistDetailInfo>
                           <cost>30</cost>
                        </ServicePricelistDetailInfo>

<PricelistDetails>
```

I'v created an Xpath assertion to  assert the cost tag to a user defined variable:

/Envelope/Body/GetServicePricelistResponse/GetServicePricelistResult/ServicePricelistInfoList/ServicePricelistInfo/PricelistDetails/ServicePricelistDetailInfoList/ServicePricelistDetailInfo/cost ='${COST1}'

whilst COST1 is defined as below :

name : COST1

Value :[20,25,30]

but when running the test plan it is showing an assertion error

Note:

I 've created an Xpath extractor to test the assertion query and it returned all 
of the cost values from the response correctly

Comment: Xpath assertion consumes more memory and CPU. You can go for xpath extractor to check for the cost. You can use regular expression extractor and use if controller to check the cost.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would suggest putting your XPath query into [XPath Extractor](http://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#XPath_Extractor), adding [Debug Sampler](http://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#Debug_Sampler) afterwards and checking the generated variables via [View Results Tree](http://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#View_Results_Tree) listener, my expectation is that you will get something like:

```
cost=20
cost_1=20
cost_2=25
cost_3=30
cost_matchNr=3
```

So you will be able to use "normal" [Response Assertion](http://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#Response_Assertion) against these `${cost_1}`, `${cost_2}` and `${cost3}` variables.

---

If for some reason you need to go the "XPath way" - use the following XPath Expression in the assertion:

```
concat("[", //PricelistDetails/ServicePricelistDetailInfo[1]/cost, ",", //PricelistDetails/ServicePricelistDetailInfo[2]/cost, ",", //PricelistDetails/ServicePricelistDetailInfo[3]/cost, "]")="${COST1}"
```

Demo:

[image: XPath Assertion Demo]

References:

- [XSLT, XPath, and XQuery Functions](https://www.w3schools.com/xml/xsl_functions.asp)
- [XPath Language Specification](https://www.w3.org/TR/xpath/)
- [How to Use JMeter Assertions in Three Easy Steps](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/how-use-jmeter-assertions-3-easy-steps)

Answer (score 0):

Your expression will just compare each of values from returned array (`20`, `25`, `30`) with `[20,25,30]` like:

```
20 = [20,25,30] # false
25 = [20,25,30] # false
30 = [20,25,30] # false
```

and return `false` as all comparissons failed, while you need to compare all of them at once:

```
[20,25,30] = [20,25,30] # true
```

I'm not sure that it's the best solution, but as last resort you can try

```
concat('[', string-join(//PricelistDetails/ServicePricelistDetailInfo/cost, ','), ']') = '${COST1}'
```

Comment: Unfortunately there is no string-join function in JMeter, you have to stick to Xpath 1.0

Comment: I tried this 

concat("[", //PricelistDetails/ServicePricelistDetailInfo[1]/cost, ",", //PricelistDetails/ServicePricelistDetailInfo[2]/cost, ",", //PricelistDetails/ServicePricelistDetailInfo[3]/cost, "]")="${COST1}"

and it worked like magic